# Gnuplot animation vector

Tags: gnuplot

i am trying to make a fluid vector animation in gnuplot. To create the vector values i use FORTRAN. My FORTRAN subroutine program prints vector data in a txt file called vekdata.txt and creates another file called plotvek.txt with gnuplot commands. This subroutine is inside a do loop so for every iteration vekdata.txt gets updated.

So i was wandering how i can make an animation of this as it develops in time? Is there some simple commands? As it is now it prints a huge amount of picture to my screen. Every picture is a bit different so i know the code works.

```
do t=1,1000

call vektorplot(storu,storv,n,Re,t)

end do





open(21,access='sequential',file='plotvek.txt',status='unknown')

write(21,*)'set term png enhanced'
write(21,*)'# plotvek.txt'
write(21,*)'set output sprintf(''frame_%09d.png'',',t,')'




!animation commands
write(21,*)'set output sprintf("frame_%9d",'t,')'


close(21,status='keep')


call execute_command_line("gnuplot -persist plotvek.txt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting here an alternative.

Although I usually prefer the animated gif as [Karl answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630991/2743307), sometimes too big gifs are difficult to rented and especially for very long movies, they tend to create unresponsive applications (browser or slide presentations).

---

Basically you write to a file every *frame* and then create a movie.

In [this link](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/animation/) you have both gif and movie examples. I'm going to recall here the principles.

For every *frame* you set a png terminal and output file. As fortran command, this would be something like:

```
write(21,*)'set term png enhanced'
write(21,*)'# plotvek.txt'
write(21,*)'set output sprintf("frame_%09d.png",',n+1,')'
[...]
```

Then, once the program is run, you can create a movie:

```
mencoder mf://frame_%09d.png -mf fps=30 -ovc lavc -o my_video.avi
```

Of course mencoder has a tons of options to tune your movie.

Another alternative to `mencoder` is `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i frame_%09d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p my_video.mp4
```

Comment: I don't understand why i need a do loop, what does it do? My program is inside a do loop (see edited code). So i can just use that as a variable instead i think. So i want gnuplut to plot t=1000 pictures, then make them into a movie, i have tried to make the gnuplot commands (see edited code)

Comment: but its not working it can't read 'set output sprintf("frame_%9d",'n+1,')' command. I don't know how the syntax should look like i am writing fortran in mac, so my syntax is write(21,*)'set output sprintf(''frame_%9d',t,')'''

Comment: Sorry, you're right the `set terminal` is inside our for loop and I also forgot a `0` and a comma `,` and `.png` ... what a mess...

Comment: Yay i managed to print 1000 images :) Thank you! How do i use mencoder? Is this built into gnuplot? So you can call on mencoder inside gnuplot?My gnuplot can't seem to find any mencoder

Comment: And is there a way to short down on the number of images you want to print? Say 100 hundred instead of 1000? when t=1000

Comment: Mencoder is an external program, I updated the answer with another program that's usually used to create animation. Explaining how to use/install ffmpeg or mencoder goes beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: if you want to plot each 10 frame, it's as easy as doing an `if (mod(n,10)==10) then ..[gnuplot commands].. endif` in your fortran code. If your have alreadycreated the frames, you can glob differently : replace `frame_%09d.png` with `frame_%08d0.png`

Comment: I'm sure both mencoder and ffmpeg could take the pngs from stdin instead of temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

The `gif` terminal has an option to make a gif animation, but you have to plot it all in one call to the gnuplot script.

You could try something like this:

```
$ makevectors | gnuplot
```

where `makevectors` is the executable of your fortran code, only it prints everything to STDOUT, first

```
set term gif animation
set out 'vectors.gif'
# plus the rest of your settings
do for [i=1:100] {plot '-' using 1:2:($3*30):($4*25) with vectors}
```

, then 100 data sets, with an EOF after each. Lastly print

```
set out
```

(Ok, the output would close anyway, but just to be very orderly) and you've got a file with that gif animation.

Update: I'd recommend you move your gnuplot commands to a script file and have gnuplot call that on the command line `makevectors | gnuplot script.gp`. That way you don't have to recompile the program every time you want to change a line colour or something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what does the command "sh> makevectors | gnuplot" do?

Comment: sh> was supposed to be the shell prompt. changed it